# PHP Regular Expressions on multiple lines

Tags: php, regex

```
<table class="trailer">

------------------Begin---------------------
<tbody><tr>
<td class="newtrailer-text">
Trailer 2<br>
</td></tr>
<br>
<b>(Yahoo)</b><br>
<b>(High Definition)</b><br>
<a href="http://playlist.yahoo.com/makeplaylist.dll?sid=107193280&amp;sdm=web&amp;pt=rd">(1080p)</a><br>
<a href="http://playlist.yahoo.com/makeplaylist.dll?sid=107193279&amp;sdm=web&amp;pt=rd">(720p)</a><br>
<a href="http://playlist.yahoo.com/makeplaylist.dll?sid=107193272&amp;sdm=web&amp;pt=rd">(480p)</a><br>
<br>
<b>(Warner Bros.)</b><br>
<b>(High Definition)</b><br>
<a href="http://pdl.warnerbros.com/wbmovies/inception/trl_3/Inception_TRLR3_1080.mov">(1080p)</a><br>
<a href="http://pdl.warnerbros.com/wbmovies/inception/trl_3/Inception_TRLR3_720.mov">(720p)</a><br>
<a href="http://pdl.warnerbros.com/wbmovies/inception/trl_3/Inception_TRLR3_480.mov">(480p)</a>=
--------------END----------------

</tbody></table>
```

How would I get all the data between begin and end?
I've tried the following with no results. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
$regex = '#<td class="newtrailer-text">([^"]+)</tbody></table>#si';
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What do you want to do with the data? (Since there are probably better/cleaner ways to achieve the same).

Comment: use the dom parser not regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$regex = '#<td class="newtrailer-text">(.+)</tbody></table>#Usi';
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's [the canonical link for why you should use DOM to parse (X)HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454): **The pony, he comes.**

But here's the deal with your regex:

`([^"]+)` will only match everything up to the first occurrence of a double-quote `"`. Your regex specifies that the first double quote must occur immediately before the `</tbody>` tag or no match will be found.

Instead, try:

```
$regex = '#<td class="newtrailer-text">(.+)</tbody></table>#siU';

if (preg_match($regex, $str, $m)) {
  echo $m[1];
} else {
  echo 'No match';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will look into DOM parser's

Comment: +1 for being way faster to explain.. typing with wireless mini-keyboard in front of my tv screen sucks ;-)

Comment: but you should really make that regex ungreedy using U modifier!

Comment: @Kaii You're absolutely right in principle. If there aren't multiple occurrences of `</tbody></table>`, (as in the posted code) though, it makes no difference. All the same, vigilance is always welcome. Updating :) Oh, and I feel your pain on the mini-keyboard. I used to try to answer questions on my phone. Then the downvotes came for slowness and autocorrect. I don't do that anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use non-greedy RrgEx like this:

```
if (preg_match_all('#------------------Begin---------------------(.*?)--------------END----------------#s', $str, $m) )
   print_r ( $m[1] );
```